# Random characters starts showing on terminal on Ubuntu 20.04.3 TS

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I see below characters on Ubuntu 20.04.3 which is wierd. I am new to Ubuntu so please assist with this issue.

1. Random characters like given below shows up on terminal
2. Even when characters dont show up, the sound of repeated keyboard typing is heard.
3. Randomly it starts deleting the entered characters, like backspace character being pressed

^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^["^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^

or
"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

Comment: Is it happening **only** in terminal?

Comment: Random characters are shown only on Terminal. But deleting the characters happens on every editor.

Comment: It seems you have an hardware problem.

Comment: Keyboard? How to confirm the same? Can it be repaired or resolved?

Comment: Yes, keyboard. If it's a laptop try booting a live session just to confirm if the symptom persists or not (adding an external keyboard won't rule out anything). If it's a desktop the first thing to try is indeed a different keyboard.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, thanks.. this solution worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your <kbd>Delete</kbd> (not your <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) key is stuck or faulty. The terminal prints this key as `^[[3~` if it not handling special keys.

Try to release it.  If this doesn't work, and the problem persists after rebooting, clean or replace your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks.. this worked